# Vowpal Wabbit - Specifying the full name of a namespace with option --keep

Tags: variables, namespaces, vowpalwabbit

I have to following situation: I would like to **keep specific namespaces** when calling Vowpal Wabbit to train it on a dataset.

The ***"--keep"*** option takes as an argument **the first letter** of the namespace. **But what if two namespaces begin with the same letter, and I want to keep only one of them ?**

> 1.00 |A1 var1 var2 |A2 var3 var4
>
> vw train_data.vw --keep "A1" ==> *impossible as keep takes only one character*

One "dirty" solution would be to rename each namespace so that they all start with a different letter, but that isn't possible for me as I need to create a namespace for each variable,and there are way more variables than letters in the alphabet...

Any take on how to solve this problem ?

Comment: You can specify a hex character,so you have 256 namespaces. Then you could use redefine to group features as you wish.( Untested!)

Answer (score 2):

Namespaces can have longer names, but only the first letter of the name is relevant for options like `--keep`, `--ignore`, `-q`, `--cubic` etc. This is enforced by the current implementation of Vowpal Wabbit (type `char`) and is not likely to change in future. I recommend using just one-letter namespace names.

You can use both lowercase and uppercase letters as well as other printable symbols with codes < 256 for the namespace names.
You cannot use symbols with codes < 32 (not printable), 32 (space), 58 (colon), 124 (pipe) and 126–135 (reserved in [example.h](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/blob/master/vowpalwabbit/example.h#L15)), but there should be still over 200 symbols to use.

Comment: Why is the type char enforced, and not a char* ? I'm just curious about the reasons that lead to that design.

I'm writing a binder R - Vowpal Wabbit to do Generalized Linear Models. I'd like to conserve the natural syntax of R and thus be able to conserve or drop specific variables in VW (namespaces aren't used in R). One solution I found was to associate a namespace for each  variable (the name of the variable), but its problematic as two variables can easily have the same first letter. 
I'm dealing with datasets that could have easily more than 1000 variables... therefore 200 isn't enough.

Comment: A lot of VW code needs to iterate over all namespaces (well, sometimes only over the non-empty namespaces), so having a lot of namespaces would slow down VW significantly. Also it is not likely that someone will specify more that 200 `--keep` options on the command line manually. You can use `--feature_mask` to keep only the features specified in a model.